# container's border is not visible on the side where image is overflowed

Tags: html, css

```
html:
<div class="photo">
      <img src="...">

    </div>

css:
.photo {
        width: 300px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: visible;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        float: right;
      }
```

border is not visible on left side when float is "right" and border is not visible on right side when float is "left"
https://jsfiddle.net/amc9s21v/2/

Comment: I want to see oveflowed part of the image and container's border over the image at the same time

Answer (score 1):

```css
.photo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/68c/delicate-arch-2-1391623.jpg">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

overflow:auto does the job

Answer (score 0):

Try to change visible to auto

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: your solution is great.better to explain with a snipet so that others can also learn

Comment: overflowed part gets hidden in this case,
I want to see oveflowed part and container's border at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `overflow: hidden;`. Than code becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        .photo{
            width: 300px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        img{
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            float: right;
          }
    </style>


  </head>
  <body >
    <div class="photo">
       <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/68c/delicate-arch-2-1391623.jpg">

    </div>
  </body></html>
```

If you want to show overflowed area than try following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        .photo {
        width: auto;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }

      img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        float: right;
      }
    </style>


  </head>
  <body >
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/68c/delicate-arch-2-1391623.jpg">

    </div>
  </body></html>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrBZxZ)**

Comment: I want to see oveflowed part and container's border over the image at the same time